# The App in Google Play can be found by name only, not by keywords. Why?

Tags: android, search, google-play

I uploaded my app to PlayMarket a week ago, but it still can be found by name only. My app about cocktails and drinking. I trying to find it with many keywords like "cocktail", "alcohol", "spirit", "drink", but it never been found. All these words are present in the description of the application. PlayMarket founds apps about drinks and cocktails, but not mine one.

When I putting App name in search box - application is displayed in the results. Alone.
What is more - my app don't have any "similar apps", although there are any.

Why it happening? And what can I do to solve this problem?
Excuse me for my bad english and thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en) is some info on how to help optimize your listing for the search engine. I believe the reason why your app does not show when searching for those keywords is because all the other apps have such a higher weight/rank, which subsequently pushes your app further in the search results listing. This is probably the case if you can find your app with those keywords after scrolling through several pages. Also, I believe the "similar apps" is determined, not by keywords, but by users and what other applications they have viewed/downloaded as well as the genre/category of the listing. As far as what you can do, I think the best option would be to market it on your own. With more reviews and downloads, it will rise up in the search ranks.

Comment: I used all these tips when publishing my app. And no, I can't find it by keywords at all - even at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely not right, this is easiest answer I got the same answer from google. First of all I'm not sure but I think google can put some kinda app ban, basically you have app in google play market but nobody can find it.

Now let's look deeper, I have experience with this, I got 3 apps terminated and one time account ban falcely, so basically I wake up and I didn't not see any apps by keywords on night I got termination, so google puts automatically some ban and then bands really later.

I had dating app, I got 100 000 downloads 500+ reviews I ranked it and then google terminated it, in my opinion falsely but they saying their story.

So I reuploaded agan my app and started from nothing whit my sistem, after 3 days ago I got to 22 place whit my keywords I whose very happy, so next day I didn't saw my app anivere, so now it is 143 place in socal apps but it is still not ranked by keyword and there is not similar apps in right side just waiting and hoping it will sort out but I thing nothing will sort out because google is not happy when you are not paing to adwords and ranking by some systems, why google's no1 enemy is seo? Because google lose money by it, the same is here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat. My app was in the top 5 search results for specific keywords over 2 months. Suddenly my revenue dropped and I didn't know why. One month after this drop I realized that my app isn't listed when searching for these keywords I was listed before. I contacted a google employee and he told me that my store listing or my app content is marked as inappropriate to child under 10. So my app is rated for an age of 12 in my distribution countries. I included some jokes with rude humour and this is why my app must be for an audience older than 12. So now I'm fighting to get my app back to the charts when searching the keywords. I change the short description, the longer description and even the rude jokes in the app. Nothing! I asked the google employee for more information as it is important for me as I must feed some mouths. Only answer that I'm getting is always the same robot like answer: Your app is marked inappropriate...  As I'm a developer willing to change everything so my app comes up in the search results again I'm really disapointed by the developer support. I know the AdWords support which is really great but if you are a developer you're lost with yourself. 
I can imagine that your app contains some words the crawler does not like and so you are never going to be listed...

It would have been enough when google just sends out a message to those whose app is marked as inappropriate so they can change something but google just is doing this process silently.
If you have any news on your issue please give me an update as I also want to solve this matter. 
Perhaps my answer got you in the right direction so you can also "try" to do something even if you don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Google automatically picks up keyword from your title and app description. However, adding something like Keywords: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3 to your description is considered keyword spamming by Google, especially if you add the title, or the developer name of a competing app. Instead, try to include your keywords in the description in a natural manner.